# how can i transfer notes from my i phone to my computer?

Tags: notes.app

i had broken the face of my iPhone and cannot see anything on the screen. i use my phone for business porpoises and i need the "notes" app's contents on to my loner phone while my is being repaired. does anyone have any suggestions to help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If you have iCloud set up, you can manage notes at http://www.icloud.com.

If you did not sync the note data to iCloud, you'll need to access a backup (from iTunes or from iCloud) and load all of that content onto your loaner phone, erasing the data that's currently on the loaner phone.